Do Christians believe that the laws of the Old Testament still apply today, or did Jesus end that?
I struggle a little bit in understanding the Christian belief about the OT laws as a Muslim.
One of the things that confuses me is that half of Christians say that deeds aren’t important; that salvation can only be through Jesus, believing he died on the cross for their sins.  The other half believe that "works" are also essential.
Which half is right?  What do you think will be the fate / judgement of those Christians who preach to others that "works" isn’t important?

Obviously each camp will say they are right. So I say: look at what Jesus taught and judge for yourself what is right. He taught that you must lose your life to save it. He taught that it is not those who cry “Lord, Lord” who will be saved - but those who do the will of the Father. In the parable of the sheep and goats, he separated them on the basis of their deeds with respect to the least of these. He taught that love is the fulfillment of the Law and to even go above and beyond the Law - to be Holy and Perfect as God is Holy and Perfect. The Law is a guide, but is ultimately a compromise.

You say that you are 'a Muslim'. May I ask if you are a Sunni Muslim or a Shia Muslim ?

This is a great question and one that I, as a Seventh Day Adventist, challenge most Sunday worshipping Christians. The keeping of the Seventh Day Sabbath predates the entry of sin into this world, so it has nothing to do with sacrifice! The keeping of the law part of your question is answered in the New Testament Revelation 14:12 "the patience of the saints are those who keep the commandments and have the testimony of Jesus". Clearly, the apostle John (the last of the disciples to die about A.D 100) believed that saints also keep the law!

The duplicate question was closed because it was a Truth Question, This one seems not to be as it asks what people believe.

@NigelJ I am neither. I have always been a Quranic. We believe only in Quran as in Hadith you have things that are similar to why you find in the Old Testament. For example also you have in Hadith stories of prophet Muhammad riding a flying donkey and meeting God in person. While those things aren’t mentioned in the Quran. I can explain you some more if you want but yea I’m not Sunni or Shia

@VictorKarajoli Your Q contains multiple topics: 1) faith vs. works; 2) applicability of OT laws.  For each issue, Christians have different views on this, as you well noted, but answering each question can be very complex.  Answering simply, all Christian agrees that issue #1 starts with Jesus's commandment to love God and to love neighbor as yourself (including your enemies).  This commandment is NOT what in theology is called "works".  All Christians MUST love, not in order to gain favor, but as a response to being saved by faith in Christ.  We become sons/daughters of God by faith only.

For issue #2, all Christians teach to obey the 10 commandments as under the commandment to love (a.k.a. the Great Commandment), but different groups have slight variations on how exactly the 10 commandments have to be obeyed. If you are really interested, I recommend reading this book: Five Views on Law and Gospel. The highest voted answer of the duplicate question can serve as an intro.

So there are three kinds of Muslim. I was just making the point that, yes, Christians are divided on certain matters of completely understanding matters of faith. It seems that yourselves, also, have matters that are unresolvable among yourselves.

@NigelJ You Made a great point. You are right. We even have more sects of Islam than 3, many ways and opinions. I just ask this question to learn what is the most original Christian belief. Because I don’t want my girlfriend who is about to become my wife to be following wrong believes

. . . . .   but you give the impression (to myself, at least) that you are actually challenging Christianity as such, whatever may be your circumstances. So that is how I am responding.

@NigelJ I challenge the people who added false information to Christianity not true Christians. I love Christianity and love Jesus
